# How I can get glyphs from a fraktur font and use them as identifiers?

Tags: fonts, built-in-symbols, unicode

I would like to use the fraktur-S ($\LaTeX$: `\mathfrak{S}` $\mathfrak{S}$; Unicode: "U+1D516" ) as a variable name in Mathematica, but pasting the Unicode character results in gibberish.

I'm confused because some Unicode characters I paste work just fine as variable names. Does Mathematica support only a subset of Unicode?

Comment: Have you tried `\[GothicCapitalS]`?

Comment: That looks like an enlarged version of the lowercase fraktur s (Latex: "\mathfrak{s}" $\mathfrak{s}$).

Comment: @J.M.isslightlypensive Might you know what subset of Unicode Mathematica supports?

Comment: I think it supports the range 0000 – FFFF.

Comment: If you type `\:d835\:dd16` directly into a notebook, you can make the character appear, but this seems more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: @J.M.isslightlypensive When I type that, I get the same gibberish as when trying to directly paste the Unicode character. I get 2 white rectangles, each containing 4 characters inside (i.e., the characters you told me to type).

Comment: @J.M.isslightlypensive. That doesn't work for me on macOS.

Comment: @m_goldberg, it seems to be an OS-dependent thing, yes. Like I said, more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation [tutorial/InputSyntax](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/InputSyntax.html)

[image: chars]

That the above at most allows four hex digits for a character code restricts Unicode characters to the range 0000 – FFFF.

Comment: So does that means it is impossible to enter the character that I mentioned?

Comment: @J.M.isslightlypensive mentioned that he was able to enter it by typing ```\:d835\:dd16``` directly in his notebook but I tried the same to no avail... Might it be bc I'm using online version?

Comment: @Landon: "using online version" - that may be it; please edit your question to include that information. Also, this is one of those times where a screenshot would be illustrative.